# excel 2010 macro to generate lists based on max value from user

Tags: excel, loops, macros, vba

```
If Worksheets("HR-Calc").Range("L2") = "01+" Then

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("A7").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("A8").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("A9").FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("A10").FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("A11").FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("A12").FormulaR1C1 = "6"
    Range("A13").FormulaR1C1 = "7"
    Range("A14").FormulaR1C1 = "8"
    Range("A15").FormulaR1C1 = "9"
    Range("A16").FormulaR1C1 = "10"
    Range("A17").FormulaR1C1 = "11"
    Range("A18").FormulaR1C1 = "12"
    Range("A19").FormulaR1C1 = "13"
    Range("A20").FormulaR1C1 = "14"
    Range("A21").FormulaR1C1 = "15"
    Range("A22").FormulaR1C1 = "16"
    Range("A23").FormulaR1C1 = "17"
    Range("A24").FormulaR1C1 = "18"
    Range("A25").FormulaR1C1 = "19"
    Range("A26").FormulaR1C1 = "20"
    Range("A27").FormulaR1C1 = "21"
    Range("A28").FormulaR1C1 = "22"
    Range("A29").FormulaR1C1 = "23"
    Range("A30").FormulaR1C1 = "24"
    Range("A31").FormulaR1C1 = "25"
    Range("A32").FormulaR1C1 = "26"
    Range("A33").FormulaR1C1 = "27"
    Range("A34").FormulaR1C1 = "28"
    Range("A35").FormulaR1C1 = "29"
    Range("A36").FormulaR1C1 = "30"
    Range("A37").FormulaR1C1 = "31"
    Range("A38").FormulaR1C1 = "32"
    Range("A39").FormulaR1C1 = "33"
    Range("A40").FormulaR1C1 = "34"
    Range("A41").FormulaR1C1 = "35"
    Range("A42").FormulaR1C1 = "36"
' maximum nuber of strings is currently 36. To increase follow pattern shown ie A43/37 , A44/38 etc etc.
'if maximum is changed it must be changed in all string format sections 01, 01/02, 01/02/03, & 01/02/03/04

If Worksheets("HR-Calc").Range("F2") = "STAGGER" Then
    Range("C7").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.01+"
    Range("C8").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.02+"
    Range("C9").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.03+"
    Range("C10").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.04+"
    Range("C11").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.05+"
    Range("C12").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.06+"
    Range("C13").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.07+"
    Range("C14").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.08+"
    Range("C15").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.09+"
    Range("C16").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.10+"
    Range("C17").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.11+"
    Range("C18").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.12+"
    Range("C19").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.13+"
    Range("C20").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.14+"
    Range("C21").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.15+"
    Range("C22").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.16+"
    Range("C23").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.17+"
    Range("C24").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.18+"
    Range("C25").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.19+"
    Range("C26").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.20+"
    Range("C27").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.21+"
    Range("C28").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.22+"
    Range("C29").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.23+"
    Range("C30").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.24+"
    Range("C31").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.25+"
    Range("C32").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.26+"
    Range("C33").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.27+"
    Range("C34").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.28+"
    Range("C35").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.29+"
    Range("C36").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.30+"
    Range("C37").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.31+"
    Range("C38").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.32+"
    Range("C39").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.33+"
    Range("C40").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.34+"
    Range("C41").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.35+"
    Range("C42").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.36+"

    Else

    Range("C7").FormulaR1C1 = "01+"
    Range("C8").FormulaR1C1 = "02+"
    Range("C9").FormulaR1C1 = "03+"
    Range("C10").FormulaR1C1 = "04+"
    Range("C11").FormulaR1C1 = "05+"
    Range("C12").FormulaR1C1 = "06+"
    Range("C13").FormulaR1C1 = "07+"
    Range("C14").FormulaR1C1 = "08+"
    Range("C15").FormulaR1C1 = "09+"
    Range("C16").FormulaR1C1 = "10+"
    Range("C17").FormulaR1C1 = "11+"
    Range("C18").FormulaR1C1 = "12+"
    Range("C19").FormulaR1C1 = "13+"
    Range("C20").FormulaR1C1 = "14+"
    Range("C21").FormulaR1C1 = "15+"
    Range("C22").FormulaR1C1 = "16+"
    Range("C23").FormulaR1C1 = "17+"
    Range("C24").FormulaR1C1 = "18+"
    Range("C25").FormulaR1C1 = "19+"
    Range("C26").FormulaR1C1 = "20+"
    Range("C27").FormulaR1C1 = "21+"
    Range("C28").FormulaR1C1 = "22+"
    Range("C29").FormulaR1C1 = "23+"
    Range("C30").FormulaR1C1 = "24+"
    Range("C31").FormulaR1C1 = "25+"
    Range("C32").FormulaR1C1 = "26+"
    Range("C33").FormulaR1C1 = "27+"
    Range("C34").FormulaR1C1 = "28+"
    Range("C35").FormulaR1C1 = "29+"
    Range("C36").FormulaR1C1 = "30+"
    Range("C37").FormulaR1C1 = "31+"
    Range("C38").FormulaR1C1 = "32+"
    Range("C39").FormulaR1C1 = "33+"
    Range("C40").FormulaR1C1 = "34+"
    Range("C41").FormulaR1C1 = "35+"
    Range("C42").FormulaR1C1 = "36+"
    End If
' only adds the positive string numbers to the list, all negative will be added later on in code



' ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------- 01+

' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 01/02+
ElseIf Worksheets("HR-Calc").Range("L2") = "01/02+" Then

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
    Range("A7").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("A8").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("A9").FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("A10").FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("A11").FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("A12").FormulaR1C1 = "6"
    Range("A13").FormulaR1C1 = "7"
    Range("A14").FormulaR1C1 = "8"
    Range("A15").FormulaR1C1 = "9"
    Range("A16").FormulaR1C1 = "10"
    Range("A17").FormulaR1C1 = "11"
    Range("A18").FormulaR1C1 = "12"
    Range("A19").FormulaR1C1 = "13"
    Range("A20").FormulaR1C1 = "14"
    Range("A21").FormulaR1C1 = "15"
    Range("A22").FormulaR1C1 = "16"
    Range("A23").FormulaR1C1 = "17"
    Range("A24").FormulaR1C1 = "18"


 If Worksheets("HR-Calc").Range("F2") = "STAGGER" Then

    Range("C7").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.01/02+"
    Range("C8").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.03/04+"
    Range("C9").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.05/06+"
    Range("C10").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.07/08+"
    Range("C11").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.09/10+"
    Range("C12").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.11/12+"
    Range("C13").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.13/14+"
    Range("C14").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.15/16+"
    Range("C15").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.17/18+"
    Range("C16").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.19/20+"
    Range("C17").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.21/22+"
    Range("C18").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.23/24+"
    Range("C19").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.25/26+"
    Range("C20").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.27/28+"
    Range("C21").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.29/30+"
    Range("C22").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.31/32+"
    Range("C23").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.33/34+"
    Range("C24").FormulaR1C1 = "STR.35/36+"

 Else

    Range("C7").FormulaR1C1 = "01/02+"
    Range("C8").FormulaR1C1 = "03/04+"
    Range("C9").FormulaR1C1 = "05/06+"
    Range("C10").FormulaR1C1 = "07/08+"
    Range("C11").FormulaR1C1 = "09/10+"
    Range("C12").FormulaR1C1 = "11/12+"
    Range("C13").FormulaR1C1 = "13/14+"
    Range("C14").FormulaR1C1 = "15/16+"
    Range("C15").FormulaR1C1 = "17/18+"
    Range("C16").FormulaR1C1 = "19/20+"
    Range("C17").FormulaR1C1 = "21/22+"
    Range("C18").FormulaR1C1 = "23/24+"
    Range("C19").FormulaR1C1 = "25/26+"
    Range("C20").FormulaR1C1 = "27/28+"
    Range("C21").FormulaR1C1 = "29/30+"
    Range("C22").FormulaR1C1 = "31/32+"
    Range("C23").FormulaR1C1 = "33/34+"
    Range("C24").FormulaR1C1 = "35/36+"

    End If
    ' only adds the positive string numbers to the list, all negative will be added later on in code
' ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------- 01/02+
```

code shown only has half of the macro, 01+, 01/02+ are shown however there is also 01/02/03+ and 01/02/03/04+ as well . Currently the code above works just fine, The only issue is that if I need more than 36 items in my list I have to run the macro then go in and manually add more data points. I've had to expand this macro 3 times already because of different projects. Cell M2 has the maximum number the list would go to (Currently 36), is there a faster way to do this other than my manual method, that allows users to input whatever number they need?

UPDATE: loop code (with some help from Ralph). much cleaner method and a lot less code

```
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 01+ string format
If Range("L2") = "01+" Then

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Range("m2")
Cells(6 + i, 1).Value = 0 + i
If Worksheets("HR-Calc").Range("F2") = "STAGGER" Then
    Range("c" & 6 + i).FormulaR1C1 = "STR." & Right("0" & i, 2) & "+"
        Else
            Range("c" & 6 + i).FormulaR1C1 = Right("0" & i, 2) & "+"
                End If
Next i
' ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------- 01+

' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 01/02+ string format
ElseIf Range("L2") = "01/02+" Then
maxn = Range("m2") / 2
For i = 1 To maxn
Cells(6 + i, 1).Value = 0 + i
If Worksheets("HR-Calc").Range("F2") = "STAGGER" Then
    Range("c" & 6 + i).FormulaR1C1 = "STR." & Right("0" & (2 * i) - 1, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (2 * i), 2) & "+"
        Else
            Range("c" & 6 + i).FormulaR1C1 = Right("0" & (2 * i) - 1, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (2 * i), 2) & "+"
                End If
Next i
' ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------- 01/02+

' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 01/02/03+ string format
ElseIf Range("L2") = "01/02/03+" Then
maxn = Range("m2") / 3
For i = 1 To maxn
Cells(6 + i, 1).Value = 0 + i
If Worksheets("HR-Calc").Range("F2") = "STAGGER" Then
    Range("c" & 6 + i).FormulaR1C1 = "STR." & Right("0" & (3 * i) - 2, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (3 * i) - 1, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (3 * i), 2) & "+"
        Else
            Range("c" & 6 + i).FormulaR1C1 = Right("0" & (3 * i) - 2, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (3 * i) - 1, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (3 * i), 2) & "+"
                End If
Next i
' ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------- 01/02/03+

' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 01/02/03/04+  string format
ElseIf Range("L2") = "01/02/03/04+" Then
maxn = Round(Range("m2") / 4, 0)
For i = 1 To maxn
Cells(6 + i, 1).Value = 0 + i
If Worksheets("HR-Calc").Range("F2") = "STAGGER" Then
    Range("c" & 6 + i).FormulaR1C1 = "STR." & Right("0" & (4 * i) - 3, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (4 * i) - 2, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (4 * i) - 1, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (4 * i), 2) & "+"
        Else
        Range("c" & 6 + i).FormulaR1C1 = Right("0" & (4 * i) - 3, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (4 * i) - 2, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (4 * i) - 1, 2) & "/" & Right("0" & (4 * i), 2) & "+"
            End If
Next i
' ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------- 01/02/03/04+
End If
```

Comment: You might want to look into loops (to do the work for you): http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_for_loops.html

Comment: I got the first loop for the simple 1 to max count, the next part that adds the "+" on the end I'm having no luck with, same for the combined numbers  ( 01/02+)

Comment: I added below a small code snippet just to show you how to do the thing with the "+". I guess you catch the drift and will be able to do the same with the other "combined" number. Let us know when you are running into any serious problem. Also, please update your question to reflect your improved code (you mentioned that you have been able to do something already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For i = 1 to 36
    Range("C" & 6 + i).FormulaR1C1 = Right("0" & i, 2) & "+"
Next i
```

Comment: this works for the "01+". I need to do some tinkering after lunch and I think this should work for the 01/02+ and the others

Comment: I am happy to hear that. Wishing you good luck. Let us know if you are running into a problem again.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is a bit painful.  Begin by replacing blocks of code like:

```
    Range("A7").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("A8").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("A9").FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("A10").FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("A11").FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("A12").FormulaR1C1 = "6"
    Range("A13").FormulaR1C1 = "7"
    Range("A14").FormulaR1C1 = "8"
    Range("A15").FormulaR1C1 = "9"
    Range("A16").FormulaR1C1 = "10"
    Range("A17").FormulaR1C1 = "11"
    Range("A18").FormulaR1C1 = "12"
    Range("A19").FormulaR1C1 = "13"
    Range("A20").FormulaR1C1 = "14"
    Range("A21").FormulaR1C1 = "15"
    Range("A22").FormulaR1C1 = "16"
    Range("A23").FormulaR1C1 = "17"
    Range("A24").FormulaR1C1 = "18"
    Range("A25").FormulaR1C1 = "19"
    Range("A26").FormulaR1C1 = "20"
    Range("A27").FormulaR1C1 = "21"
    Range("A28").FormulaR1C1 = "22"
    Range("A29").FormulaR1C1 = "23"
    Range("A30").FormulaR1C1 = "24"
    Range("A31").FormulaR1C1 = "25"
    Range("A32").FormulaR1C1 = "26"
    Range("A33").FormulaR1C1 = "27"
    Range("A34").FormulaR1C1 = "28"
    Range("A35").FormulaR1C1 = "29"
    Range("A36").FormulaR1C1 = "30"
    Range("A37").FormulaR1C1 = "31"
    Range("A38").FormulaR1C1 = "32"
    Range("A39").FormulaR1C1 = "33"
    Range("A40").FormulaR1C1 = "34"
    Range("A41").FormulaR1C1 = "35"
    Range("A42").FormulaR1C1 = "36"
```

with:

```
Range("A7:A42").Formula = "=rows($1:1)"
Range("A7:A42").Value = Range("A7:A42").Value
```

or:

```
    With Range("A7:A42")
        .Formula = "=rows($1:1)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
```

It will be easier to replace the **42** with a parameter than to add more lines of code.

Comment: Very nice, I used the loop form the other answer but I do like your method for producing the counter column.